# Preventing bootstrap from breaking between two form elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with the bootstrap datetimepicker and have a bit of a problem.

My problem is best explained by [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xum/p6da2kww/).

What I want to do is to have three separate form divs in a row and for them to stay in one row no matter the screen size. I would usually acchieve this by simply having a `form-group` div (as seen in the "situation I want" of the JSfiddle), however in this case, that is not possible because if I do that, then the second input messes with the javascript of the bootstrap datetimepicker, so I cannot touch the `form group` div.

Is there any way of acchieving what I want to do?

The HTML in which my problem is isolated is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        The situation right now:
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group date date-filter" id="start-date">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end-time" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        The situation I want:
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date date-filter" id="end-date">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end-time"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @nathanmac Sorry. Edited.

Comment: Probably should include the JS/jQuery as I think the solution is more likely to come from altering that than the CSS, or altering the CSS will rely on knowing what is going on with the datetimepicker.

Comment: add to the relevant class display:inline-block

Comment: @jeff Can you elaborate on that? I tried to do that, but never got anywhere...

Comment: you doesnot include the bootstrap?

Comment: @NageshwarReddy I do in the jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kwtt7jj8/ check this link

Comment: Without the bootstrap code included in your example it is difficult to ensure an accurate answer. You might want to try: .form-group { display: inline-block; } also you could include the the !important command to ensure that the bootstrap code is overridden.

Comment: @jeff What do you mean "without the bootstrap code"? The bootstrap is included into the jsfiddle...

Comment: @NageshwarReddy Thanks! Will check it out for sure.